# How to sort row values in by letter in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

so I have an excel file where I have information on some start-ups and I want to Display details of startups where the City Location starts with "s" or "p". How can I do this using pandas?

Data:

```
City  Location
Pune
Mumbai
Mumbai
Hyderabad
Burnsville
Bengaluru
Mumbai
Menlo Park
Bengaluru
Gurgaon
New Delhi
Bengaluru
Mumbai
Noida
Bengaluru
```

This not working:

```
 df[df['City Location'].str.startswith(('s','p'))]
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and expected output? 3-4 rows is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with tuple if need test column `City Location` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

EDIT: If need test uppercase values:

```
df[df['City Location'].str.startswith(('S','P'), na=False)]
```

If need test lowercase or uppercase:

```
df[df['City Location'].str.lower().str.startswith(('s','p'), na=False)]
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error "ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values"

Comment: @ArunavDongre - Add `na=False` parameter, answer was edited.

Comment: I did this and now it is just showing a blank table with just column heading what should I do now

Comment: @ArunavDongre - Not idea, because cannot see your data. Can you post sample data to question?

Comment: sure, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fVc8grq_rGj5qVyR6QAKSVpFbw8Jg9s1/view?usp=sharing